# How to Execute/Trigger a method before an ArrayObject is accessed with a certain Key

Tags: php, php-7

I have a php ArrayObject

```
class myObject extends ArrayObject
{
   
    public function __construct()
        parent::__construct(array(), ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);
       // populate 
       $this->populateArray();
    {

    private function populateArray() {
       $this['hello'] = null;
       $this['hello2'] = null;
       $this['hello3'] = null;
    }
}
```

Now when I access the hello element in this way

```
 $myArray = new myObject();
 $value = $myArray['hello'];
```

I would like to trigger a method in the myObject that assigns to $myArray another object before being read.
My medhod should look like this.

```
 private function method($value) {
    $this[$value] = new class2();
 }
```

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: Looks like 2 separated questions

Comment: What is not clear ? I would like a method to be triggered .

Comment: You can look at `__get()` but you'll need a private/protected array.

Comment: You can override `offsetGet`

Comment: Call a method in constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwritte `offsetGet` function like this:

```
    public function offsetGet($index) {
        $this->someMethod();
        return parent::offsetGet($index);
    }
    
    private function someMethod()
    {
        echo "triggered";
    }
```

Then when you run

```
$x = new myObject;
echo $x['hello'];
```

Will output

> triggered

In `someMethod()` you can do whatever you want.